# Prove that the two distinct bases of ideal $I$ will have identical affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a proposition here that states

> If $f_1,\ldots,f_2$ and $g_1,\ldots,g_t$ are bases of the same ideal $I$ in some field $k$, so that $\langle f_1,\ldots,f_s\rangle=\langle g_1,\ldots,g_t\rangle$ then we have that $V(f_1,\ldots,f_s)=V(g_1,\ldots,g_t)$

Apparently, my lecturer left the proof as "very straightforward" and didn't touch on it. Unfortunately, I am unable to prove it. Here' s my attempt and question,

> Let $(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \in V(f_1,\ldots,f_s)$. Then, we clearly have $V(f_1,\ldots,f_s) \subseteq V(I)=V(\langle g_1,\ldots,g_t\rangle)$ since if each $f_1,\ldots,f_s$ disappears for any such $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ then the span will consequently vanish.

My question is, I need to show $V(f_1,\ldots,f_s) \subseteq V(g_1,\ldots,,g_t)$ and vice versa but not $V(f_1,\ldots,f_s) \subseteq V(\langle g_1,\ldots,g_t\rangle)$. And I don't think $V(\langle g_1,\ldots,g_t\rangle)=V(g_1,\ldots,g_t)$ so to me, this isn't straightforward at all.

So how do I go about this? Please tell me what I need to do

Comment: What does $V$ stand for?

Comment: the affine variety or vanishing set of the polynomials

Comment: Note: $\langle f_1,\ldots,f_s\rangle$ is standard usage; $< f_1,\ldots,f_s>$ is not. I changed it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I didn't know that, cheers for changing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are confused about the following statement:

**Lemma.** Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $f_1, \ldots, f_s \in k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$, and set $I = (f_1, \ldots, f_s)$. Then $V(f_1, \ldots, f_s) = V(I)$.

*Proof.* Let $x \in \mathbb A^n$. If $x \in V(I)$, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $f \in I$. In particular, setting $f = f_i$ gives $x \in V(f_1,\ldots, f_s)$.

Conversely, if $x \in V(f_1,\ldots,f_s)$, then $f_i (x) = 0$ for all $i \in \{1,\ldots,s\}$. If $f \in I$, then there exist $a_i \in k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ such that $f = \sum a_i f_i$. Thus,
$$f(x) = \sum a_i f_i(x) = \sum 0 = 0.$$
$\square$

Comment: Hi There, thanks for answering, this looks very useful in solving my case; just to check( notations are confounding from time to time) when you say $I=(f_1,...,f_s)$ up there in the statement of the lemma, by that, it's equivalent to my $<f_1,...,f_s>$ (i.e. the "span" $h_1f_1+...+h_sf_s$ where $h_i \in k[x_1,...x_n]$), yes? The lemma is essentially saying $V(I)=V(<f_1,...,f_s>)=V(f_1,...,f_s)$(seems like it from the proof, but just a double check)

Comment: Yes, by $(f_1,\ldots,f_s)$ I mean the ideal generated by $f_1, \ldots f_s$.

Comment: Brilliant, an on-the-spot answer, thanks so much again!

Answer (score 1):

The polynomials that are zero on a given set, even the zero set of a given set of polynomials, form an ideal, so they must contain the ideal generated by the given set of polynomials.

On the other hand, if a collection of polynomials has a common zero $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ then any linear combination of those polynomials (with arbitrary polynomials as coefficients) also has that zero.

Comment: I don't really understand the first sentence there. As for the second, that is exactly how I concluded that $V(f_1,...f_s) \subseteq V(I)$ since $I$ is generated by $f_1,...,f_s$, thus the elements are the linear combination of the polynomials $f_1,...,f_s$. But my issue is although $V(f_1,...f_s) \subseteq V(I)$, I cannot straight away find a logical reason to state $V(f_1,...f_s) \subseteq V(g_1,...g_t)$. This might be answered in your first sentence, but can you extend on that?

Comment: Surely if you make the collection of polynomials smaller, the zero set can only become larger (or stay the same)?